# Python - duplicated lines

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I am new on Python. I would like to find the duplicated lines in a data frame.
To explain myself, I have the following data frame

```
type(data)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

`data.head()`

```
   User Hour    Min Day Month   Year    Latitude    Longitude
0   0   1   48  17  10  2010    39.75000    -105.000000
1   0   6   2   16  10  2010    39.90625    -105.062500
2   0   3   48  16  10  2010    39.90625    -105.062500
3   0   18  25  14  10  2010    39.75000    -105.000000
```

I would like to find the duplicated lines in this data frame and to return the 'User' that corresponds to this line.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: There are no duplicated lines in this data. What constitutes duplicate in this case? Did you check the docs? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

Comment: Did you check other SO questions such as this one that provides a very clear answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244309/how-to-analyze-all-duplicate-entries-in-this-pandas-dataframe

Comment: I tried the Counter from collection to begin with, so it can give me the **number** of duplicated data. But Counter works only on single column data frame. @Chris

Comment: Thanks a lot @WoodyPride, I have not seen this

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
user = data[data.duplicated()]['User']
```